# how to filter data from html table

Tags: php, html

This is a code i used to prase a data through html dom php and echo a data in table form 
all data came in perfect table form. but i want to show only 5 out of all data echo in table.at last i used table to echo a content or data i want only to echo 5 data out of all showing out but i am not getting any idea to code this.. any one can help me to do this?

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html         = file_get_html('http://www.discoverhongkong.com/us/see-do/events-festivals/events-calendar/index.jsp');
$eventRowData = array();

class eventRecord
{
    public $dates;
    public $eventDescription;
}
;
foreach ($html->find('#event_table tr') as $eventItem) {
    $eventDateArray = array();
    $oneEventData   = new eventRecord;

    foreach ($eventItem->find('.date') as $eventDate) {
        $oneDateData = array();
        $dom         = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $dom->loadHTML($eventDate);

        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
        $hTwo                    = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
        foreach ($hTwo->childNodes as $dateElement) {
            array_push($oneDateData, $dateElement->nodeValue);

        }
        //print_r ($oneDateData);
        array_push($eventDateArray, $oneDateData);

    }

    //
    $oneEventData->dates = $eventDateArray;

    $eventData = null;
    foreach ($eventItem->find('.event_name') as $eventName) {

        $dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

        $dom->loadHTML($eventName);

        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
        $baseLink                = "http://www.discoverhongkong.com";

        $img = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);

        $relativeLink = $img->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->value;
        $eventLink    = $baseLink . $relativeLink;

        $eventData = '<strong><a href="' . $eventLink . '" title="' . $img->textContent . '">' . $img->textContent . '</a></strong><br />';

        $oneEventData->eventDescription = $eventData;
        //echo $oneEventData->eventDescription;
    }

    array_push($eventRowData, $oneEventData);
}
$arr = array_values($eventRowData);
//Print_r ($eventRowData);
//echo "----------";
//echo $arr[0]->eventDescription;
//echo "----------";
echo '</br>';




echo '<h2>Events In HongKong</h2>';
echo '<table class="table-bordered">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th class="abc">EVENT NAME</th>';
echo '<th>START DATE</th>';
echo '<th>END DATE</th>';
echo '</tr>';

foreach ($arr as $xyz) {
    //print_r ($xyz);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo ($xyz->eventDescription);
    echo '</td>';


    //$mydates = array_values($xyz->dates);
    //print_r ($mydates);
    foreach ($xyz->dates as $datevalue) {
        //echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        foreach ($datevalue as $datevalueitem) {
            echo $datevalueitem;
            echo '/';
        }

        echo '</td>';

    }
    echo '</tr>';



}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want to display the first 5 elements in the loop, regardless of how many there are?  Keep a count in an integer variable.  When it reaches 5, break out of the loop.

Comment: yes i want to do same can you help me with a code or example i am new here..

Comment: do a for loop from 0 to 4 over your array, instead of a foreach which processes everything in the array

Comment: @ADyson Using a for loop would break if the HTML happened to have less than 5 elements.

Comment: @GordonM in that case from 0 to the size of the array, or 4, whichever is less

Answer (score 2):

Which of these loops is the one you want to restrict?  Whichever one it is, the structure would be the same.  Something like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $i++;
    if ($i > 5) {
        break;
    }
    // the rest of your loop code
}
```

So you're basically storing in `$i` (or whatever you want to call the variable) a count of how many times the loop has executed.  After 5 times, you use `break;` to exit the loop, regardless of how many records remain.